# How to query 3 tables with one to many relationship along with json aggregation?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have 3 tables like shown below with some sample data:

countries

| id | name | leader |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | India | Narendra Modi |
| 2 | USA | Joe Biden |
| 3 | Australia | Scott Morrison |

states

| id | name | population | country_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | California | 39500000 | 2 |
| 2 | Washington | 7610000 | 2 |
| 3 | Florida | 21500000 | 2 |
| 4 | Karnataka | 64100000 | 1 |
| 5 | Rajasthan | 68900000 | 1 |
| 6 | Maharastra | 125700000 | 1 |

cities

| id | name | state_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mumbai | 6 |
| 2 | Pune | 6 |
| 3 | San Francisco | 1 |

I would like to get all the countries with their states and cities queried by population. The result should look like this:

```
[
  {
    "country_name": "USA",
    "leader": "Joe Biden",
    "states": [
      {
        "state_name": "California",
        "population": 39500000,
        "cities": [
          {
            "city_name": "San Fransico"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "country_name": "India",
    "leader": "Narendra Modi",
    "states": [
      {
        "state_name": "Maharastra",
        "population": 125700000,
        "cities": [
          {
            "city_name": "Mumbai"
          },
          {
            "city_name": "Pune"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I was able to achieve this somewhat with sub queries like this:

```
select *,
  (
          select
            array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(states.*))) as array_to_json
          from (
                select states.*, (
                  select
            array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(cities.*))) as array_to_json
            from(
              select cities.* from cities where state_id = states.id
            ) cities) as cities
                 from states
                         where country_id = countries.id and population=125700000 OR population = 39500000
               ) states ) as states
from countries;
```

But I'd like to use a neat query where I can achieve this using a single join query with JSON aggregators in Postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
WITH list AS
(
SELECT s.country_id
     , jsonb_build_object( 'state_name', s.name                         , 
                         , 'population', s.population
                         , 'cities', jsonb_agg( jsonb_build_object('city_name', c.name))
                         ) AS state_list
  FROM states AS s
 INNER JOIN cities AS c
    ON c.state_id = s.id
 GROUP BY s.country_id, s.name, s.population
)
SELECT jsonb_agg( jsonb_build_object( 'country_name', c.name
                                    , 'leader', c.leader
                                    , 'states', l.state_list
                                    )
                )
  FROM list AS l
 INNER JOIN countries AS c
    ON c.id = l.country_id
```